# Interactive visualization - select which csv to visualize

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, interactive, plotly-python

I'm writing an interactive visualization code using Python.
What i would like to do is to create an interactive visualization which allows the user to select a file from a dropdown menu (or something like that) and then plot a barplot of the selected data.

My data folder has the following structure:

```
+-- it_features
|   +-- it_2017-01-20--2017-01-27.csv
|   +-- it_2017-01-27--2017-02-03.csv
|   +-- it_2017-02-03--2017-02-10.csv
```

and so on (there are many more files, I'm just reporting few of them for simplicity).

So far I'm able to access and retrieve all the data contained in the folder:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
path = os.getcwd()
file_folder = os.path.join(path,'it_features')


for csv_file in os.listdir(file_folder): 
    print(csv_file)
    file = os.path.join(file_folder,csv_file)
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    #following code....
```

What I would like to do is create an insteractive visualization which allows the user to select the file name (for example it_2017-02-03--2017-02-10.csv) and plot the data of that file.

I'm able to select "by hand" the file I want and plot its data by inserting its filename in a variable and then retrieving the data, but I would like not to insert it via code and allow the final user to browse and select one of the files using a dropdown menu or something similar.

My simple code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
path = os.getcwd()
file_folder = os.path.join(path,'it_features')
file = os.path.join(file_folder,'it_2020-02-07--2020-02-14.csv') # Here I insert my filename
df=pd.read_csv(file)
ax=df.value_counts(subset=['Artist']).head(10).plot(y='number of songs',kind='bar', figsize=(15, 7), title="7-14 February 2020")
ax.set_xlabel("Artist")
ax.set_ylabel("Number of Songs Top 200")
```

Which generates the following plot:
[image: Barplot]

As I already said, I would like to introduce a somewhat drodown menu that allows the user to select the csv data he wants to plot using an interactive plot.

I saw that it's possible to create dropdown menus with Plotly, but in the various examples (https://plotly.com/python/dropdowns/) it doesn't seem to select and then load the data.

I also saw this code ([Kaggle code](https://www.kaggle.com/benhamner/python-plotly-dropdown-demo)) which seems to do what I wanted to do: you can select the region and plot the data from that region.

The main problem is that he just creates a big unique dataframe with US states, and then creates a trace for each one of them.

What i would like to do (if possible) is to select the file name from the dropdown, load the csv and then plot its data, without creating a single giant dataframe with all my files in it.

Is it possible?

**EDIT**: The solution proposed by ***gherka*** works perfectly, but I would like to have a solution inside Plotly using its dropdown menu.

Comment: Are your users going to interact with the app on a web page or exclusively via a jupyter notebook?

Comment: @gherka Only jupyter, everything is written and "self-contained" inside my notebook

Comment: If your using `jupyter` then using `ipywidgets`(like mentioned in the answer below) might be a good choice but if you want to come back to python and IDE later on then you can use `messagebox` from `tkinter` too.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're working in Jupyter Notebook, you have a number of different options.

Some visualisation libraries will have built-in [widgets](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#dropdown) that you can use, however they would often require you to run a server or provide a javascript callback. For a library-agnostic approach, you can use `ipywidgets`. This library is specifically for creating widgets to be used in Jupyter Notebooks. The documentation is [here](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

To create a simple dropdown with a static bar plot underneath, you would need three widgets - `Label` for dropdown description, `Dropdown` and `Output`. `VBox` is for laying them out.

```
from ipywidgets import VBox, Label, Dropdown, Output

desc = Label("Pick a .csv to plot:")

dropdown = Dropdown(
    options=['None', 'csv1', 'csv2', 'csv3'],
    value='None',
    disabled=False)

output = Output()

dropdown.observe(generate_plot, names="value")

VBox([desc, dropdown, output])
```

[image]

The key element is the `generate_plot` function. It must have a single parameter that you use to decide what effect the widget action has on your plot. When you interact with the dropdown, the `generate_plot` function will be called and passed a dictionary with "new" value, "old" value and a few other things.

Here's a function to generate a basic `seaborn` bar chart with an adjustable data source. Notice I had to include an explicit `plt.show()` - plots won't render otherwise.

```
def generate_plot(change):
    with output:
        output.clear_output() # reset the view
        if change["new"] != "None":
            data = pd.read_csv(...) # your custom code based on dropdown selection
            sns.catplot(x="Letters", y="Numbers", kind="bar", data=data)
            fig = plt.figure()
            plt.show(fig)
```

If you have many large .csv files, one other thing is you might want to do is implement a caching system so that you keep the last few user selections in memory and avoid re-reading them on each selection.

For a more in-depth look at how to add interactivity to `matplotlib` plots using `ipywidgets` I found this [tutorial](https://kapernikov.com/ipywidgets-with-matplotlib/) quite useful.

Comment: This is great! Could you please provide an example of the function generate_plot with seaborn? I've been trying myself to make it work, but unfortunately I failed

Comment: Sure. Edited to include a sample function.

Comment: I manage to make it work, works perfectly. I'll wait to accept the answer since I would like to have also an alternative inside Potly using its dropdown menu. Still, this solution is pretty good

Answer (score 0):

tkinter is a super common UI framework for python, and is part of the standard library. Based on answers in a similar question, you can use this:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
filename = askopenfilename()
```

which pops up a standard file explorer window.

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio Yes this will

Comment: actually, I missed that this was in jupyter. This suggestion may not work in jupyter, but will work on a standard python environment running on your computer